# Trouble installing Phalcon with MAMP PRO - PHP 7.0.8

Tags: php, installation, phalcon, mamp-pro

I am having some trouble installing phalcon on my Macbook Pro with MAMP. I used this guide to do my installation (https://www.extreme-creations.co.uk/blog/how-to-install-phalcon-php-framework-with-mamp-on-osx/), I also tried this guide (https://github.com/majksner/php-phalcon-mamp) but no luck either. I did my testing using this  but i couldn't find "=> phalcon" in the array.

I tried to load up phpinfo() and i couldn't find phalcon extension. and this is the

1. path Configuration File (php.ini) Path /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.8/conf
2. Loaded Configuration File /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/php.ini
3. Scan this dir for additional .ini files (none)
4. Additional .ini files parsed (none)

however, the Loaded Config file path, I went there but the conf folder doesn't even exist. any help would highly appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Following these advices may help you:

- follow these steps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32963161/1100671
- ensure that you're editing the correct php.ini by reading value from php function `echo php_ini_loaded_file();`
- if none of precompiled files work, you can try to compile it by yourself.